# Does there exist an equivalent of ERC-1167: Minimal Proxy Contract on solana?

Tags: solana-program

Does there exist an implementation of ERC-1167: Minimal Proxy Contract on solana?

Answer (score 1):

Not yet, unfortunately. All on-chain programs must have their own program id and bytecode, and cannot use the bytecode from another program. The change required to support this functionality needs to be done at the protocol level, and there's no plan to do it at the moment.